# Limit JS event to once per day per user

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am hoping to limit the event below to once a day per user. This will be a shadowbox that appears when the user tries to leave the page. I don't want to annoy the user with this every time their mouse leaves the body, so it should only happen the first time they are on the site each day.

```
$('body').one('mouseleave', function() {
    $('.shadowbox').fadeIn(400)
});
```

I have been advised that using a cookie would be a good way to do this, but I am inexperienced in using cookies. Thank you!

Comment: I would still go with cookies. Local storage won't help you here..

Comment: either use `cookies` or use `localStorage` with object storing information with timestamp

Answer (score 2):

You can set the cookie in that function with an expiry.

Good documentation is available on this [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).

Basically, do a check and set in that function.

```
$('body').one('mouseleave', function() {
    var cookie = document.cookie; //You need to find the cookie you need here (if it exists, don't do anything)
    return; //if exists
    $('.shadowbox').fadeIn(400)
    document.cookie = "myCookieName=true; expires=(datetime + 1day)"
});
```

That way, you only get to fade and setting if there isn't a cookie available.

Answer (score 0):

You can find infos about using cookies with javascript here : [How do I create and read a value from cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie)

Then, assuming you're using the solution above :

```
$('body').on('mouseleave', function() {
    var cookie = getCookie('visited');
    if ('' == cookie) {
        $('.shadowbox').fadeIn(400);
        createCookie('visited', 'yes', 1);
    }
});
```